# Python - Unable to modify the serializer.data dictionary in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, dictionary, django-rest-framework

I have tried to add a key `serializer.data['test'] = 'asdf'`, this does not appear to do anything.

I want to transform the representation of a key's value. To do this, I'm trying to use the value to calculate a new value and replace the old one in the dictionary.

This is what I want to accomplish, but I don't know why the value is not being replaced. There are no errors thrown, and the resulting dictionary has no evidence that I've tried to replace anything:

```
class PlaceDetail(APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        place = Place.objects.select_related().get(pk=pk)
        serializer = PlaceSerializer(place)
        #serializer.data['tags'] = pivot_tags(serializer.data['tags'])
        serializer.data['test'] = 'asdf'
        print(serializer.data['test'])
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Terminal: `KeyError: 'test'`

I have observed by printing that `serializer.data` is a dictionary.

I have also tested that the syntax I'm trying to use should work:

```
>>> test = {'a': 'Alpha'}
>>> test
{'a': 'Alpha'}
>>> test['a']
'Alpha'
>>> test['a'] = 'asdf'
>>> test
{'a': 'asdf'}
```

How can I properly modify the `serializer.data` dictionary?

Comment: Are you sure `pivot_tags` would replace the value? Show the code maybe

Comment: Yes I'm sure `pivot_tags` works, that method is used in another APIView with no problem. I've boiled it down even simpler by just adding a single key and it still doesn't work: `serializer.data['test'] = 'asdf'`

Comment: You are returning `Response(serializer.data)` not `serializer.data`. How did you use the return value?

Comment: The framework handles the return, I haven't looked into it. But this problem occurs before then... immediately I try to print `serializer.data` and the key I just tried to add is not there. Which leads me to believe that this is not a normal dictionary, perhaps read-only?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `Serializer.data` property returns an `OrderedDict` which is constructed using `serializer._data`. The return value is not `serializer._data` itself.

Thus changing the return value of `serializer.data` does not change `serializer._data` member. As a consequence, the following calls to `serializer.data` are not changed.

```py
# In class Serializer(BaseSerializer)
@property
def data(self):
    ret = super(Serializer, self).data
    return ReturnDict(ret, serializer=self)

# In class ReturnDict(OrderedDict)
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.serializer = kwargs.pop('serializer')
    super(ReturnDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can keep a copy of the return value of `serializer.data`, which is an ordered dictionary, and manipulate it as you wish.

Example:

```
# keep the return value of serializer.data
serialized_data = serializer.data
# Manipulate it as you wish
serialized_data['test'] = 'I am cute'
# Return the manipulated dict
return Response(serialized_data)
```

Why:

If you look at the source code of Django Restframework, you will see that in `Serializer` class,

- `Serializer._data` is just a normal dictionary.
- `Serializer.data` is a method decorated to act like a property. It returns a `ReturnDict` object, which is a customized class derived from `OrderedDict`. The returned `ReturnDict` object is initialized using key/value pairs in `Serializer._data`.

If `Serializer.data` returns `Serializer._data` directly, then your original method will work as you expected. But it won't work since it's returning another dictionary-like object constructed using `Serializer._data`.

Just keep in mind that the return value of `Serializer.data` is not `Serializer._data`, but an ordered dictionary-like object. Manipulating the return value does not change `Serializer._data`.

I believe the reason why `serializer.data` does not return `serializer._data` directly is to avoid accidental change of the data and to return a pretty representation of `serializer._data`.

Comment: Could you please  provide example code of how to add or replace something in the dictionary?

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense, so basically I have to create a copy instead of modifying the original. You said that this is because operating on `serializer.data` doesn't change `serializer._data`, can you explain why there are these two? Are these dictionaries special/different from normal?

Comment: I've updated some explanation in the last part. Hope it can help :p

Comment: @Rikka I wish I could give you more upvote. I wasted 3 hours on this. :(

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) instead of explicitly overwrite the representations.

Comment: Inside `def get_tags(self, obj):`, the object can be accessed by `obj`, but how can I access the dictionary?

Comment: Please **paste** necessary code. I didn't see this from your question.

Comment: It is in the second line of the question, the thing I'm adding is based on a value in `serializer.data` dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Building further on @yuwang's answer, I used `SerializerMethodField` to modify value of a particular field in the serializer. Here's an example:

The field that I wanted to modify, let us call it `is_modifyable`. This field is present on the Django Model as `models.BooleanField` and hence it was not present in the list of fields on serializer definition and simply mentioned in the `class Meta:` definition under within the serializer definition.

So here's how my code looked before:

```
# in models.py
# Model definition
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    is_modifyable = models.BooleanField(default=True)

# in serializers.py
# Serializer definition
class SomeModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ('is_modifyable',)
```

As a result of the above, the value for the field `is_modifyable` was always fetched on the basis of what the value was in the record of `SomeModel` object. However, for some testing purpose, I wanted the value of this field to be returned as False during the development phase, hence I modified the code to be as follows:

```
# in models.py
# Model definition (Left unchanged)
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    is_modifyable = models.BooleanField(default=True)

# in serializers.py
# Serializer definition (This was updated)
class SomeModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # This line was added new
    is_modifyable = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ('is_modifyable',)

    # get_is_modifyable function was added new
    def get_is_modifyable(self, obj) -> bool:
        """
        Dummy method to always return False for test purpose
        Returns: False
        """
        return False
```

Once the above code was in, the API call always returned the value of serializer field `is_modifyable` as False.